# c# mvc ef The property does not exist or is not mapped for the type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I developed my site with "Database First".
With Entity Framework I have a model class User from database.
I want to add a property to this class that it won't be in database.
How is this possible?

Here is what I tried.
User.Custom.cs

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UserMapping))]
public partial class User
{
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Password does not match")]
    [NotMapped]
    public string ConfirmNewPassword { get; set; }
    public class UserMapping
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

But I am getting the error:

> The property 'ConfirmNewPassword' does not exist or is not mapped for
>   the type 'User'.

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: In view you should use model which is not from database, and then in controller map it into db model and save.

Comment: ok, but is there any better solution? because ef makes my life easier.

Comment: what means a better solution? in that case you should separate the model from your Data Transfer Object (DTO). The property "ConfirmNewPassword " has nothing to do in the ef-model. Just create an UserDto, give them the needed properties and on registration create a new user-object if the ConfirmNewPassword from the UserDto is the same.

Comment: Ok. Thank you both of you for your help. I did this (different model for view) and everything is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not best approach, but if you insists on using it, try `partial class` with attribute `NotMappedAttribute` over property, it should work.

If it didn't help, try to use db context configuration

Comment: it is the same with `NotMaped`.. I tried but same result.